# Log-linear regression: interpretation of RSE

Tags: regression, interpretation, log-linear

**AIM:** To really, really understand what the model outputs mean in a log-linear regression, specifically, how to interpret the residual standard error (RSE).

I have read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120443/interpretation-of-logged-regression) but it does not specifically address RSE for log-linear models.

This is the log-linear model:

```
lm(formula = log(n_capita) ~ edu_index_percent, data = full_maps_edu)
```

So far, to my understanding I know that the RSE is the average amount that the response will deviate from the true regression line. Great. But because I have logged the dependent variable, can I say:

- `n_capita` will deviate on average about 1.33 from the true regression line?

I think that should't make sense because the response variable is logged. Should it instead be:

- `n_capita` will deviate on average about $e^{1.33}$ from the true regression line?

I'm a bit confused. Please advise.

```
  Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)       -9.92029    0.38053   -26.1 <0.0000000000000002 ***
    edu_index_percent  0.10345    0.00592    17.5 <0.0000000000000002 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Residual standard error: 1.33 on 167 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.646, Adjusted R-squared:  0.644 
    F-statistic:  305 on 1 and 167 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```