# Interpretation of log(1 + x) transformed predictor

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, interpretation, logarithm

[Interpretation of log transformed predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor) neatly explains how to interpret a `log` transformed predictor in OLS. Does the interpretation change if there are 0s in the data and the transformation becomes `log(1 + x)` instead?

Some authors (e.g. Fox and Weisberg 2011) recommend adding a `start` (i.e. a positive constant) if a `log` transformation is necessary to correct skewness and improve symmetry, but the data contains zeros.

Consider a variation of the `Ornstein` example in CAR (p. 303):

```
require(car)
data(Ornstein)
boxplot(Ornstein$interlocks, horizontal = T)
```

[image]

The data is clearly right skewed, and contains 0s.

```
summary(powerTransform(1 + Ornstein$interlocks))
## bcPower Transformation to Normality 
## 
##                         Est.Power Std.Err. Wald Lower Bound Wald Upper Bound
## 1 + Ornstein$interlocks    0.1248    0.053           0.0209           0.2287
## 
## Likelihood ratio tests about transformation parameters
##                              LRT df      pval
## LR test, lambda = (0)   5.502335  1 0.0189911
## LR test, lambda = (1) 262.431991  1 0.0000000
```

The `powerTransform()` function suggests that a `log(1 + x)` transformation here could be useful.

```
boxplot(log(1 + Ornstein$interlocks), horizontal = T)
```

[image]

As you can see, symmetry is indeed improved.

**Question:** If this transformed variable were to be included in an OLS regression as an IV, would the coefficient estimates still have the usual interpretation of `log` transformed variables?

Answer (score 5):

It depends. According to Wooldridge (2012) the percentage change interpretations are often closely preserved, except for changes
beginning at $y = 0$ (where the percentage change is not defined).
Strictly speaking, using $\log(1+y)$ and then interpreting the estimates as if the variable were $\log(y)$ is acceptable only if the data on $y$ contain relatively few zeros.

Comment: Do you have a page number for Wooldridge?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov In Wooldridge 2009 it's p.192 (Chapter 6.2 More on functional form).

Comment: In the 2012 EDT (US version), it is at the button of page 193

Comment: This answer is not quite correct and might be misleading.  What matters isn't whether $y$ includes "relatively few zeros," but the actual *values* of $y$ relative to $1.$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576504 for more accurate answers.