# How to interpret a log transformed (x+c)?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation, logarithm

I need to use log-log regression and because I have lots of zero values I tried to add a very small constant c=8E-12 to x and it works pretty good. Xs are very small probabilities.

**ln*Y= a + b* ln *(x+c)***

But how do I interpret that model? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you tell us something about the original model and data, why "you need" to use log-log regression, and how the results will be used?

Comment: I´m trying to create model for my bachelor thesis. I use gravity model to explain influence of religion on international trade and log-log regression is the very simple solution.

Comment: Also closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20397, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18694.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I checked all of them, but now I see I missed few.

Comment: "Generally, using log(1+y)log(1+y) and then interpreting the estimates as if the variable were log(y)log(y) is acceptable when the data contain relatively few zeros" says Wooldridge. But what if I have lots of zero values?

Comment: The first link in my comment directly addresses the situation where "many variables contain many zeros."  If you think you need to review more posts about this, http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+log+zero turns up some useful ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are asserting (not testing) that x cannot actually be zero but rather that you simply cannot measure (or control) it below a certain level.

If it is a dose, for instance, you are asserting that there is always some of the compound in the background environment.  If it is light, you are asserting that there is some background level of photons, etc.

The problem is, your $c$ is a guess and may bias the results even if your assertion is true.  You may want to try several values.

Your model is related to $Y = e^a (x+c)^b \times \epsilon$.

If you intend to fit $Y = e^a (x+c)^b + \epsilon$ then how you fit the model matters.  You maybe could estimate $c$ as a parameter but this could be problematic and may not be worth the bother.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I am just asking how to interpret that, not how to make model the right way.

Comment: I thought my first  two paragraphs answered the interpretation question.  I guess not.